# Download update before asking for restart

Tags: macos, software-update, auto-update

Every now and then my Mac informs that there is an Update that needs a restart to install. Once I click on Details, there is a Button to install the update and restart. But once I click that one, there is a Download of more than a gig pending.

I would like to change this behaviour, such that the notification only appears when the Update is already downloaded. Is that possible? How can I achieve this?

Checking "Automatically keep my Mac up to date" doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Did you check the advanced options on the update tab? What macOS version are you running?

Comment: All options in the Advanced tab are checked. Mojave, 10.14.6.

Comment: Your odds of having already downloaded the update are higher if you leave your computer charging (or turned on) overnight. However (now I will speculate), according to the documentation, it makes sense to me that it will try to prompt you whenever you are using the computer on whether it can restart your Mac for updates that require it. If you give it permission, just forget about it and it will reboot and update when you are not using it after downloading (provided it is charging, in case it's a MacBook). https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201541

Answer (score 2):

You might need to check the boxes "Check for updates" and "Automatically download updates when available" for the download. Also, Check firewall options for allowing connections if denied.

https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/where-are-downloaded-software-updates-stored.1629444/ and as I too verified, updates are located in `Library/Updates` before install.  You can verify if it is available for install or not.

Comment: They're all checked already. Does that mean there is something fishy with my Mac?

Comment: @user1785730 I won't say fishy. There might be simple things like network problems, insufficient storage or low battery. You can delete the updates in the said folder, uncheck all boxes, check the boxes and wait for the folder to rebuild. But is there an update available after 10.14.6?

Comment: The update was installed by now. Might've been 10.14.5 before.

Comment: However, this isn't something new. EVERY time an update came, the notification to restart came LONG before the update was downloaded.

Comment: @user1785730 you can go to About this Mac -> system report -> software -> installations and sort by date or Apple/3rd party to see the date of update. RE 2nd comment, I am afraid I can help only so much.

Comment: Interesting: I've just installed 'macOS Mojave 10.14.6 Supplemental Update'. The 'macOS 10.14.6 Update' came about a month ago.